# Spaces in File directory

Tags: java, file, directory, runtime, execution

I was writing a program to be able to run external files using Java. I have searched up how to run a .bat file and none of the solutions are working. It seems that the problem is there is a space in one of the directory names for the file im trying to run. When I run the program, a Windows error comes up that reads

```
Windows cannot find 'C:\Users\Brandon's'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again
```

For refrence the actual Users file name is Brandon's Pc, it seems that it does not read the file directory correctly if there is a space. What do I do? I am unable to find a solution online. Thank you for the help!

Program Code for Refrence, in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");

//System.getProperty("user.dir") gets the directory of the java file

     File file = new File(currentDirectory+"\\src\\Start.bat");
     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
     PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(writer);

//Writing information to a .bat file

     outFile.println("cd "+currentDirectory+"\\src\\CC\\CD\\");
     outFile.println("start CD.exe -o \"LC.txt\"");
     outFile.println("cd "+currentDirectory+"\\src\\ACr\\");
     outFile.println("BD.exe -f \"LAB.txt\"");
     outFile.println("exit");

//closes PrintWriter

     outFile.close();

//Excuting the /bat file

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+file);
 }
```

Comment: Did you tried quotes, like `.exec("cmd /c start \"" + file + "\"")`?

Comment: Ok, it opened a CMD this time, but is not running the code inside of the .bat file, but if I manually run the .bat file by double clicking, it correctly executes.

Comment: You might want to try [escaping spaces](http://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks) using the caret symbol "^".

Comment: when you say that, replace the spaces with the carat symbol "^"?